# Convert RDS Database Instance to Aurora Cluster

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have an existing database instance in RDS. I'd like to take a snapshot of this database instance and restore it to a new Aurora cluster.

How can I do this? I would think this would be a common thing, but can't seem to figure out the steps to make this happen.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Migrating.html

Comment: Migrate was what I was looking for. Thank you. I couldnt seem to find anything via google.